# List<> propertychanged event

Tags: c#

I am working on a project in which I need to notify my GUI that my list has new items.

I tried this with an observablecollection, but I use timers, and when I try to add or remove items from the observablecollection, then an exception is thrown that the collection is being marshalled from another thread.

Therefore, I started thinking about using the PropertyChanged event. However, I have trouble with getting it to work. What I understand is that it is used for properties. I have tried the following code without success:

```
public class MyCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ConcurrentQueue<PC_Info_Item> data;

    public List<string> table;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        data = new ConcurrentQueue<PC_Info_Item>();
        table = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(PC_Info_Item item)
    {
        data.Enqueue(item);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(table));
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        table.Add(item);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(table));
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        data.TryDequeue(out PC_Info_Item item);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(table));
    }

    public void delete_string(string item)
    {
        table.Remove(item);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(table));
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work for lists?

Comment: You know about - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged - seems to me the more fitting interface?

Comment: *"exception is thrown that the collection is being marshalled from another thread"* - I'd rather invoke the calls, done. Don't mix observable collection used by views and collection used to efficiently implement model functionality into one.

Comment: I m on my phone do I don't post as "answer", because I m not confortable with code writing on it, but the first comment is right, and to adress your threading problem you have to raise the PropertyChanged évent on the UI thread, by calling Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the calls into lock, that will make other threads wait till the call is finished.

```cs
    private readonly object CollectionLock = new object(); 
    
    public void Add(PC_Info_Item item)
    {
        lock(CollectionLock) {
            data.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        lock(CollectionLock) {
            table.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        lock(CollectionLock) {
            data.TryDequeue(out PC_Info_Item item);
        }
    }

    public void delete_string(string item)
    {
        lock(CollectionLock) {
            table.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call on property changed as below where we should get the invocation list and call invoke on each receiver with lock.

```c#
private object _lock = new object();
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = "")
{
  var receivers = this.PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList();
  foreach (EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> receiver in receivers)
  {
    lock (this._lock)
    {
      receiver?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
  }
}
```